# Unable to update iPhone via Applescript "update" command

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, applescript

I've been using an applescript to automatically sync a device with iTunes. Recently, the script has stopped working and I cannot figure out for the life of me why.

Here is the small script:

```
set deviceName to "iPhone5"
tell application "iTunes"
    activate
    set src to (some source whose name contains deviceName)
    tell src to update
end tell
```

but recently I get an error that src doesn't understand the message update. I've recently updated the MacOS as well as XCode to version 9. I also have checked in ScriptDebugger and src is of type source and is valid when I ask it to update.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Seems hard to find much help on applescript.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on the latest version of Sierra

```
set deviceName to "iPhone"
tell application "iTunes"
    activate
    set src to (some source whose name contains deviceName)
    update src
end tell
```